# JAVA - SQL server insert string value into varbinary(max) data type

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a string value and insert the SQL server into varbinary(max) data type

My code:

```
String fullText ="abcd"
byte[] binaryFullText = fullText.getBytes();
 preparedStatement.setBytes(33, binaryFullText);
preparedStatement.execute();
connection.commit();
```

but its inserted like `"0x4E18ACADEBE27B0ADEAAE"`

Do I want to insert the actual value in DB how? and sometimes my string exceeds the max limit of varbinary(max) so in this situation.

How can I insert the entire value into the field?

Comment: The maximum storage size for varbinary is 2^31-1, which is simply huge.  Did you really exceed this?  `but its inserted like ...` If you inserted a byte array, then you _did_ insert the actual value.

Comment: first i used setstring() if reached max limit its not inserted the entire string value so then i changed the datatype as varbinary(max), and used setBytes()

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I could think of would be to create an alternative table if you truly are exceeding the max value. 
Lets assume that the value in question is data and is inside the table foo where

```
-----foo-----
foo.id
foo.data_id
foo.descpit
```

Create another Table

```
-----bar------
bar.id
bar.data
```

now you can link as much data to the foo.data_id as you want simply by adding more entries into the bar table with the correct ID.

This also allows you to change the value of the field to text which would store plain text. I do not believe that you can store bits into a field and expect to read Plain text

you loose some flexibility, but you gain the ability of unlimited theoretical storage.